# how to save and access Dictionary into SQL Server Database in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, windows-services, using-statement

the below code works me using Dictionary, i want the same to save Dictionary into SQL Server Database.

> Actually my problem is, I am using windows service, I want to start
>   the connections when service start and stop connections when service
>   stop and also want to access the connection objects outside service

We have more than 1 dynamic connection objects and we save into dictionary
and then pass to function on each iteration, it works

```
private IDictionary<string, ConnectionManagerIdle> dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, ConnectionManagerIdle>(); 
// get list of client
List<Guid> clientids = EmailSync.clients();
// on service start
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
      ConnectionManagerIdle conn = new ConnectionManagerIdle()
      dictionary.Add(clientids[i].ToString(), conn);
      EmailSync.IMapIdle(dictionary[clientids[2].ToString()], clientids[2]);
  }
}
// on service stop
protected override void OnStop()
{
   dictionary[clientids[i].ToString()].Stop();
}
```

else is there a way to save the Dictionary into DB and return back to access it any time outside its service scope.
may be i totally wrong but please guide how can I resolve my problem.
I appreciate your valuable time, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to use those connections later, simply do not use a `using`. But then you might need another way to dispose them. Not enough info here for a full solution.

Comment: @HenkHolterman can you plz provide me ideal solution for?

Comment: @HenkHolterman it works me, if i make dynamic object without using statement. but again i have another problem, is there a way to save these dynamic objects into DB instead of dictionary.

Comment: @HenkHolterman can you plz see my question again, i updated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the variables outside `using` block as they are disposed once the block gets executed, that's what `using` block is for.

For more information, read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

If you want to use the same connection afterward then don't use `using` block, in that case, you need to be very careful while handling objects which is also not preferred way of doing it.

Comment: e.g, if we do not use using statement, is there a way , our dynamic objects will work outside?

Comment: In that case you will need to make the connection variables global as you will face error of WeakReference, I guess

Comment: did you see my code, if we make object globally, so we can not use in loop the same object. do you have any suggestion about.

Comment: You _could_ access the variable (by a little rewriting), but it would point to a Disposed and therefore useless object.